# The spring data rest's behavior looks weird

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a project with spring data rest that when I run it does not have some expected features. When I go to http://localhost:8080/rest-api/profile, the following links appear, which the repository related to each of them has extended CrudRepository.

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest-api/profile"
    },
    "roles": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest-api/profile/roles"
    },
    "users": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest-api/profile/users"
    },
    "offers": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest-api/profile/offers"
    },
    "businesses": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest-api/profile/businesses"
    },
    "apps": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest-api/profile/apps"
    },
    "addresses": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest-api/profile/addresses"
    },
    "contacts": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest-api/profile/contacts"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when I go to the http://localhost:8080/rest-api/users/search, the following page opens:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "getByEmail": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest-api/users/search/getByEmail{?email}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "getByRoleName": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest-api/users/search/getByRoleName{?role}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "existsByEmail": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest-api/users/search/existsByEmail{?email}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest-api/users/search"
    }
  }
}
```

**First question:**

1-Why does not the spring data rest expose method for CrudRepository's specific methods? like findAll ro findById ?Are they not the search method?

**Second question:**

When I open http://localhost:8080/rest-api/apps/search it gives a 404 not found error.

Why does it give an error when I go to the search link related to apps? Don't apps have search methods? In addition, when I go to the mentioned link, the following line is logged in the program console:

```
2022-10-24 11:02:14.990  WARN 7560 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException: EntityRepresentationModel not found!]
```

I would be really appreciated if you would answer me.

Comment: Where is the path `http://localhost:8080/rest-api/apps/` defined? Did you mean `http://localhost:8080/rest-api/profile/apps/`?

Comment: Because it is about resources **not** about repository methods. Normally `/users` would list all users and thus call the `findAll` method. The `/users/{id}` would get the specific user (and call the `findById` method). You have to think in resources and not methods. Non default methods are exposed, by default, by name and parameters (you can change this using the Spring Data REST annotations).

Comment: @dunni rest-api is the base path for my rest API. when I go to this link it lists all apps and their links like self or profile.

Comment: @M.Deinum Is it possible to determine what those settings are or at least give me a link?

Comment: The Spring Data REST documentation explains all of that.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.http-methods

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you, is it possible to say what is the difference between method and resource? Basically, what does resource mean in spring data rest? And basically, what is the reason that all CrudRepository methods are not exposed?

Comment: They are exposed (POST will call `save` etc). That is basically what http resources are. It isn't dumb exporting all methods of the repository it is smarter then that.